# Raspberry Pi Pico W Current Sensor - SCT-013-000, ADS1115

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm attempting to build a project that monitors the current of a 240v circuit that typically runs in the 35 amp range when energized. This doesn't need to be super super accurate (I know there are some issues with speed of samples in this set up), but I'd like it to be close enough to just give a general idea of behavior of the appliance connected.

I've tried other versions of code and other hardware setups, but currently I'm using a Raspberry Pi Pico W, connected over I2C with 3.3v to an ADS1115. From there, pins A0 and A1 are tied to a 22 ohm resister that connects either side to either wire of the SCT-013-000 (a 100A:50mA current transformer). See diagram below for hardware:
[image: Hardware diagram]

This setup and the code (which was pieced together from a YouTube tutorial and altered to fit the setup I'm running, and the ADS1115 micropython library, the original code (not the one I'm using, but the one the project has parts from, and is based on is here, along with a copy of the ADS1115 library: [HERE!](https://github.com/brendena/pico_power_monitor/blob/main/ads1115.py)) I'm currently running to get the current produces results, however it doesn't produce results anywhere near what's expected, and I'm not sure how to calibrate it or otherwise what I may be doing wrong from a math standpoint.

The code produces a result that behaves as expected (being, that when the circuit the sensor is measuring is deenergized, the result is very low (<0.005) and when energized the current value increases, but it doesn't increase to what should be on that circuit (verified by a multimeter clamp).

```
import machine
from math import sqrt
from ads1115 import ADS1115
from time import sleep_ms, ticks_ms, ticks_us, sleep

ADC_RATE = 5 # in ms

class ADC:
    def __init__(self, ADS,maxCurrent,maxVoltage, channel1, channel2 = None):
        self.ADS = ADS
        self.maxCurrent = maxCurrent
        self.maxVoltage = maxVoltage
        self.readTotal = 0
        self.readCount = 0
        self.channel1 = channel1
        self.channel2 = channel2
    def read(self):       
        self.ADS.set_conv(7,self.channel1, self.channel2)
        
        for x in range(0, 120):
            sleep_ms(ADC_RATE)
            self.readTotal += self.ADS.read_rev() ** 2.0
            self.readCount +=1
        
    def getAmps(self):
        voltage = self.ADS.raw_to_v(sqrt(self.readTotal/ self.readCount ))
        current = (self.maxCurrent / self.maxVoltage) * voltage 
        print("voltage " + str(voltage))
        print("current " + str(current))
        self.readTotal = 0
        self.readCount = 0
        return current  
  
def main():
        while True:
            self.ADC.read()
            amps = self.ADC.getAmps()
            #then we handle other stuff

i2c = machine.I2C(1, scl=machine.Pin(15), sda=machine.Pin(14))


STC_ADS = ADS1115(i2c,address=0x48, gain=1)
STC = ADC(STC_ADS,100,3,0,1)
time.sleep(1)
main()
```

There are other functions I removed that handle wifi, handle the data after we calculate it, and some other things removed from main() relative to those as well, but the issue I have currently is that the result that is determined from the calculations in getAmps(), change when there is current being sensed correctly, but the value is far from correct.

As I mentioned, this sensor is watching a (multimeter verified) circuit that pulls 35 amps, and the code returns a value around 11-12 amps. (i didn't write down the voltage value that gets printed before current)

```
current 11.87473647
```

and on the lower end, a circuit tested at 120v, with 1.2 amps confirmed returns:

```
current 0.44298728
```

I'm wondering if this is an issue relative to the burden resistor/maxVoltage value or gain or something in the math that I'm not considering.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide! I had to remove a bunch of stuff from the code that would be unnecessary for this information, so I may have messed something up in syntax when doing that, but the basis of the math and how the circuit is wired are accurate to how they're done in the entire project.

Comment: I would hazard to guess that your issues are with the type of resistor being used (i.e what is it's tolerance), the ADC quantization error, and/or the fact that at 35 amps, the is reading a maximum of .77 volts across your resistor.

Comment: @itprorh66 22ohm resistor, 5% tolerance, 1/4w.

Comment: https://how2electronics.com/ads1115-16-bit-adc-module-with-raspberry-pi-pico/

Comment: Multiplying the result that self.getAmps() returns by 3 seems to give me very close to correct amperage in both of those examples. I'm not sure if it's the way it should be done, but seems to be functioning closer to expected now.